# change WindowClass to full screen

Tags: c++, winapi, window

so am trying to make my window class full screen, but it's not working , it just flickers black then it does not become full screen here is the source code :-

```
void InitEngine::Init(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd, DesktopScreenInfo * ScreenInfo, LPSTR WindowName)
{
    mWindoClass = new WNDCLASSEX();
    ZeroMemory(mWindoClass,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    if(ScreenInfo) mScreenInfo = ScreenInfo;
    else mScreenInfo = &DesktopScreen::GetScreenInfo();

    mWindoClass->cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);// window size
    mWindoClass->style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; // so it draw when Horizontal or Vertical change
    mWindoClass->lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    mWindoClass->hInstance     = hInstance;
    mWindoClass->hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); //load normal cursor
    mWindoClass->hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    mWindoClass->lpszClassName = "PoPEngineClass";

    DEVMODE screen;
    memset(&screen,0,sizeof(screen));
    screen.dmSize = sizeof(screen);
    screen.dmPelsWidth = mScreenInfo->Width;
    screen.dmPelsHeight = mScreenInfo->Height;
    screen.dmBitsPerPel = mScreenInfo->ScreenDepth;
    screen.dmDisplayFrequency = mScreenInfo->FrameRate;
    screen.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL|DM_PELSWIDTH|DM_PELSHEIGHT;
    ChangeDisplaySettings(&screen, CDS_FULLSCREEN);

    RegisterClassEx(mWindoClass);

    WindowHandel = CreateWindowEx(NULL , mWindoClass->lpszClassName , WindowName , WS_POPUP, 0 , 0, mScreenInfo->Width, mScreenInfo->Height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(WindowHandel, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(WindowHandel);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does ChangeDisplaySettings return? It has return codes which indicate if it was successful. Secondly have you got a simple WM_PAINT responder that paints the screen an obvious colour?

Answer (score 0):

ChangeDisplaySettings does not actually make a window full-screen - despite the perhaps misleading name of the flag. To make a window go full screen, you basically have to do a bunch of work yourself:

- remember the old position
- change the window style to remove the borders and titlebar
- get the screen size, set the window's new position to cover the screen
- and put it on top of other windows (the latter two you can do with the SetWindowPos call.)

There's a couple of answers to this same question [elsewhere on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382464/win32-full-screen-and-hiding-taskbar) -- but there's problems with them. Instead recommend reading Raymond Chen's blog entry on this: [How do I cover the taskbar with a fullscreen window?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx) - the difference between what he's doing any my list above is that he's creating a new window without vs modifying an existing one; which is actually a neater approach as it means you don't need to deal with remembering/restoring the old position.

ChangedisplaySetting's `CDS_FULLSCREEN` flag has a different meaning: the call is for changing display mode settings, not making a window fullscreen; but the flag is telling windows that the mode change is temporary, so should't be saved. For example, if an app that plays back video at a specific resolution is going full screen, it might want to change the actual screen resolution to match the video, but just so long as it is full screen. Or a OpenGL game or similar might use this to ensure it is running full-screen with a specific resolution. So it really means "change the display settings to these, but I'm doing this just because I'm going fullscreen, so don't make the change permanent'. Raymond Chan writes a bit more about this flag [on his blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/04/6973747.aspx). If you don't care about the screen resolution settings, and you just want your window taking up all of the screen area, then you don't need this call.