# Can I show a window without showing Windows Explorer taskbar?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have created a new window using C + Win32 API, and I attached it to a game.

The game runs on `Windowed (no border)` mode, which means that it's simply a big window which is shown over the taskbar, creating the effect of a full-screen mode.

I've binded <kbd>F11</kbd> to pop-up the console with:

```
ShowWindow(hConsole, SW_HIDE);
ShowWindow(hConsole, SW_SHOW);
```

That pop-ups the console window, and it works fine, except that it also shows the taskbar.

Is there any way to make the game still stay over the task bar, while showing the console?

Comment: This seems to be solved here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382464/win32-full-screen-and-hiding-taskbar

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Thanks, but I think that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to show the console over the taskbar, but rather keep the game over the taskbar, AND then pop the console over the game.

Comment: I see. In that case it might be prudent to describe your problem in a little more detail.

Comment: Why not (auto-)hide the task-bar?