# C++ "var foo = !!::bar()" syntax ?

Tags: c++, syntax, cwnd

Looking for some explanation on how going fullscreen mode with HWND window, I found this response [Win32: full-screen and hiding taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382464/win32-full-screen-and-hiding-taskbar)

The chromium response code has this line:

```
saved_window_info_.maximized = !!::IsZoomed(hwnd_);
```

from this file https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/ui/views/win/fullscreen_handler.cc?revision=HEAD&view=markup on line 56

I read:

```
var bar equal not not of mother method
```

Is this correct ?

What this "!!::IsZoomed()" means ?

Why not just

```
saved_window_info_.maximized = CWnd::IsZoomed(hwnd_);
```

?

Comment: !! is used to transform any non-zero value into a boolean true / false. some compillers can be quite picky.

Answer (score 10):

The `!!` is simply `!` and `!`, two negations. Double negation reduces to noop, but it casts the value to `bool`. So consider that an alternative syntax to `(bool)`. It's advantage is that it:

1. it works in C which did not have a separate bool type in C89 (forces the value of 0 or 1) and
2. MSC++ does not generate the silly “performance warning” for it like it does for `(bool)`.

And the rest is simply `::IsZoomed`, i.e. function `IsZoomed` from top-level namespace.