# Is there any option to Run Flutter Windows Desktop application in full screen mode

Tags: flutter

I have tried flutter Windows Desktop application, but I am not able hide title bar to run app in full screen mode windows

Answer (score 12):

I guess [window_manager](https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager) can achieve your needs

### Installation

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
 dependencies:
  window_manager: ^0.2.7
```

### Usage

```
// Enter fullscreen
await WindowManager.instance.setFullScreen(true);
// Level fullscreen
await WindowManager.instance.setFullScreen(false);
```

Comment: It's the perfect one as of now

Comment: It's on pub.dev now, so no need to pull from the git repository anymore.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager

Answer (score 7):

Got the same problem and I'm here to share my solution.

I'm not a Win32 developer but I managed to make a basic fullscreen this way.

This code works for my Flutter version 1.21.0-10.0.pre.114, I hope it will for you too.

My solution is heavily inspired by this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416613/14093885

You have to edit ./windows/runner/main.cpp

Insert the following code between these statements around line 30:

```cpp
window.SetQuitOnClose(true);

//Insert Code Here

run_loop.Run();
```

Code to insert :

```cpp
//HWND is window handler
HWND hwnd = window.GetHandle(); 

auto windowHDC = GetDC(hwnd);
int fullscreenWidth  = GetDeviceCaps(windowHDC, DESKTOPHORZRES);
int fullscreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(windowHDC, DESKTOPVERTRES);
int colourBits       = GetDeviceCaps(windowHDC, BITSPIXEL);
int refreshRate      = GetDeviceCaps(windowHDC, VREFRESH);

DEVMODE fullscreenSettings;
bool isChangeSuccessful;

EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, 0, &fullscreenSettings);
fullscreenSettings.dmPelsWidth        = fullscreenWidth;
fullscreenSettings.dmPelsHeight       = fullscreenHeight;
fullscreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel       = colourBits;
fullscreenSettings.dmDisplayFrequency = refreshRate;
fullscreenSettings.dmFields           = DM_PELSWIDTH |
                                      DM_PELSHEIGHT |
                                      DM_BITSPERPEL |
                                      DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY;

SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST);
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE);
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, fullscreenWidth, fullscreenHeight, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
isChangeSuccessful = ChangeDisplaySettings(&fullscreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN) == DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL;
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

EDIT - Flutter 2:

According to @Pavel the last line `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);` is not needed in Flutter 2.

Comment: The flutter emulator freezes when I try this. Are you sure it's just a matter of pasting that code in?

Comment: I'm not sure about it depending on the version of flutter your using. If it's the one I was using that should work but I would not be surprised to learn that it changed with flutter 2.0.

If you are using the good `window` that should be okay I think.
Anyway I am not a win32 dev so if that's not it my method probably is outdated.

Comment: @Tunnelvisie if you are using Flutter 2, remove this line: `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);`

Answer (score 4):

Use this package: https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager

In your main, add this code after 'RunApp':

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
// Must add this line.
await windowManager.ensureInitialized();

// Use it only after calling `hiddenWindowAtLaunch`
windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async {
// Hide window title bar
await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle('hidden');
await windowManager.setFullScreen(true);
await windowManager.center();
await windowManager.show();
await windowManager.setSkipTaskbar(false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the plugin window_size: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/window_size

```
@override initState() {
super.initState();
Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((finish) async {
  if (Platform.isMacOS) {
    // * FULL SCREEN
    PlatformWindow window = await getWindowInfo();
    setWindowFrame(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, window.screen.frame.width, window.screen.frame.height));
  }
});
```

}

Comment: That code will give you a decorated window that's the size of the screen. There will still be a title bar, resize handle, menu bar, etc. That's not the same as full screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think it must change the cpp file now.

win32_window.cpp
replace "WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW" with "WS_POPUP | WS_MAXIMIZE"

/*
WS_POPUP : without title bar
WS_MAXIMIZE : full screen
*/

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for full-screen mode yet, so there's no Dart API you can call to enter full screen. If you are familiar with Win32 programming, you could either change the Runner code directly to make the window full screen, or write a plug-in that does it.

Answer (score 1):

this is the link for more help [window Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles)
I have Done this in this way
I get window size from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles

in flutter windows app for window size :
go to
windows/runner/win32_window.cpp

- for fullscreen window without titlebar WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE
- for fullscreen window with titlebar(without any icon such as
  close,minimize,restore,logo) WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_VISIBLE
- for small or customized window WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE
- for fullscreen window with titlebar WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE |
  WS_VISIBLE

Find this CODE given below in win32_window.cpp file and change as you wish.

```
HWND window = CreateWindow(
  window_class, title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_VISIBLE,
  Scale(origin.x, scale_factor), Scale(origin.y, scale_factor),
  Scale(size.width, scale_factor), Scale(size.height, scale_factor),
  nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I wanted only a popup window to be full screen, not the whole app. So I needed a solution that worked together with the desktop_multi_window plugin - that's why I couldn't use the window_manager plugin which was suggested in other answers.

**Windows**

Open `windows/runner/flutter_window.cpp`

Add the include `#include "desktop_multi_window/desktop_multi_window_plugin.h"` at the start of the file, below the other includes

Search for the line containing `RegisterPlugins` and add the following code right below that line:

```
DesktopMultiWindowSetWindowCreatedCallback([](void *controller) {
  auto *flutter_view_controller = reinterpret_cast<flutter::FlutterViewController *>(controller);
  if (flutter_view_controller->view() != nullptr) {
    HWND subHwnd = flutter_view_controller->view()->GetNativeWindow();
    HWND hwnd = GetParent(subHwnd);
    if (hwnd != nullptr) {
      DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
      MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) };
      if (GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY), &mi)) {
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle & ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.top, mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top, SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now every new window you create with the desktop_multi_window plugin will be shown in full screen.

I know the question was specific for Windows, but since Flutter works on all platforms you might also want to support the full screen mode in macOS and Linux.

**macOS**

Open `macos/Runner/MainFlutterWindow.swift`

Add the import `import desktop_multi_window` at the start of the file, below the other imports

Search for the line containing `RegisterGeneratedPlugins` and add the following code right below that line:

```
FlutterMultiWindowPlugin.setOnWindowCreatedCallback { controller in
  controller.view.window?.toggleFullScreen(self)
}
```

**Linux**

Open `linux/my_application.cc`

Add the include `#include "desktop_multi_window/desktop_multi_window_plugin.h"` at the start of the file, below the other includes

Search for the line containing `fl_register_plugins` and add the following code right below that line:

```
desktop_multi_window_plugin_set_window_created_callback([](FlPluginRegistry* registry){
  g_autoptr(FlPluginRegistrar) registrar = fl_plugin_registry_get_registrar_for_plugin(registry, "DesktopMultiWindowPlugin");
  FlView* view = fl_plugin_registrar_get_view(registrar);
  if (view != nullptr) {
    gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(gtk_widget_get_toplevel(GTK_WIDGET(view))));
  }
});
```